# Google Forms response in new sheet with notification

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've created a order capture form that captures the 
1. location (dropdown), 
2. delivery date (date)
3. Products (small text)

I have then added a formula to generate a new order no. everytime a new response is added.

```
=arrayformula( if( len(A2:A), "Order " & text(row(A2:A) - row(A2) + 1, "022"), iferror(1/0) ) )
```

I need a new sheet to be created with the tab name with the new order no. and the columns transposed along with the response inputs against them.

For example response form

```
    Column B  | Column C |  Column D      |Column E   |Column F
    Order no. | Location |  Delivery Date | Product 1 | Product 2
    Order 122 | XYZ      |  2/16/2017     | 35kg      | 45kg
```

New sheet generated named "Order 122"

```
Order no.     | Order 122
Location      | XYZ
Delivery Date | 2/16/2017
Product 1     | 35kg
Product 2     | 45kg
```

and a notification to be sent to an email.

Is this possible with google spreadsheets, if so, please do let me know how it can be done. Thank you in advance.

I am using the following to create a new sheet named after the order no. but it doesnt seem to be working based on this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305238/create-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-spreadsheet-for-each-response-from-a-google-fo).

```
function subTheForm(){
  Logger.log('submit ran');

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var colB_Data = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();
  ss.insertSheet(colB_Data);

};
```

I get this error when I run the script

```
The sheet name cannot be empty. (line 9, file "Code")
```

Comment: look at the documentation for insertSheet.

Comment: Looks that ColB_Data is empty. Double check that the last row, second column isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I used the following code similar as what I'd posted. For some reason I kept getting an error, cleared the responses, deleted and recreated the script and triggers and it worked.

```
function onSubmit(e){
  Logger.log('submit ran');

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //Get last row of data
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var colB_Data = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();

  ss.insertSheet(colB_Data);
};
```